# Check if answer is correct MCQ

Tags: php

Basically I am implementing a MCQ question. Everything is quite simple. Single form with all questions(pulled from DB) and options.

I am stuck at the place where i need to check if the answers selected by the user are correct or not.

There is a separate DB with the correct option corresponding with all questions
like

```
array(q_1 => 3,
      q_2 => 2,
      q_3 => 4,
      ); //just an example
```

Code:

This one is a failed attempt

```
public function checkAnswers($submition){
    //compare array with db right answers
        $correct = array();
    foreach ($submition as $attempt){
            $x = 0;
            if ($attempt == $this->_db->get('answers', array('q_id','=','1')){
                $correct[$x] = "yes";
            }

    }
    return $correct;
    //$this->displayFinalScore()
}
```

This is how i am getting the submittions

```
$score->checkAnswers(array(
                    'question1'     => Input::get('question1'),
                    'question2'     => Input::get('question2'),
                    'question3'     => Input::get('question3'),
                    'question4'     => Input::get('question4'),
                    'question5'     => Input::get('question5'),
                    'time'          => 300,
                )));
```

Please tell me if you need more code for helping me before voting the question down.
Thanks.

Thanks for your help Andrew but i took a different approach and figured it out. Here is the answer:

```
    public function checkAnswers($submition){
    //compare array with db right answers
    $answers = $this->getAnswerKey();
    //$answer->q_id == question id & $asnwer->option_id == correct answer
    //submittion for each question in loop is $submition[$question->q_id]
    foreach ($answers as $answer) {

        if($submition[$answer->q_id] == $answer->option_id){
            $this->score = $this->score + 4;
        }
    }
    $this->createEntry($this->score, $submition['user_id']);

}
```

Hope this will help someone in need!

Comment: If your `checkAnswers` isn't working - what is wrong with it? Is it saying everything is wrong? Everything is right? Giving the wrong answers? Which part specifically isn't working? Do you go into the foreach loop? Are the variables in the foreach being set properly? Is it the database check that isn't working?

Comment: @andrewsi It just checks the first item in the array.

Comment: Alright. Question: how sure are you that it just checks the first item in the array? Add an echo to your loop so that you can see every time it's called and see how many times it's run.

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks. I figured it out. Answer posted.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question and mark it as "accepted" after the minimum time has elapsed - we don't modify title tags to have "solved" in them when a question is answered.

Comment: @HetuNandu - for what it's worth, the issue with the code you posted is where you create your array. You're assigning values to `$correct[$x]`, but you assign `$x = 0` inside your loop, and never change it, so your returned array will only ever have a single value.